# ASP.NET получить данные из GridView

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webforms

У меня есть GridView в котором определен некий шаблон вывода данных, из этих данных мне нужно вытащить "Имя" которое расположено в LinkButton, чтоб потом передать его другой странице, через строку запроса. Не знаю как это сделать. К LinkButton я не могу обраться, только могу использовать его событие(собственно через его событие я буду переходить на другую страницу).

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Style="margin: 0px auto" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Процессоры">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    <div style="float: left; margin: 30px">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" Height="200" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Image") %>' />
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" runat="server"><%#Eval("Name") %></asp:LinkButton>
                        <br></br>
                        <font color="#808080"> Семейство процессора: </font><%#Eval("Processor_Family") %>
                        <br>
                        <font color="#808080"> Тип разъема: </font><%#Eval("Connector_Type") %>
                        <br>
                        <font color="#808080"> Внутренняя тактовая частота: </font><%#Eval("Unlocked_Multiplier") %>
                        <br>
                        <font color="#808080"> Количество ядер: </font><%#Eval("Number_Of_Contacts") %>
                        <br>
                        <font color="#808080"> Объем кэш памяти 3 уровня: </font><%#Eval("Cache_Memory_Level_3") %>
                        <br>
                        <font color="#808080"> Интегрированная графика: </font><%#Eval("Integrated_Graphics") %>
                    </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте обработать `OnCommand` вместо `OnClick`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" 
    CommandName="SomeCommand"
    CommandArgument="<%#Eval("Name") %>"
    OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command"
    runat="server"><%#Eval("Name") %>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

и достать `CommandArgument` из параметров события на сервера.

или вместо `OnCommand` обработать OnRowCommand у самого грида.

Но вообще, если вам просто надо перенаправить на другую страницу - это можно сделать без забега на сервер, через обычный `Hyperlink` или `HyperLinkColumn`.

Comment: мне нужно перенаправлять на другую страницу с одним параметром, чтоб на той тоже построился грид, с актуальной информацией. Спасибо попробую чуть позже)

Answer (score 0):

Передача name на другую страницу:

```
Response.Redirect("page.aspx?name=" + name.ToString());
```

Вытягиваем в переменную table информацию из GridView1:

```
DataTable table = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
```

[Источник](http://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/base/level5/5_2.php)

Comment: string name = Request.QueryString["name"]; // код на странице page.aspx